# Get data from a binary file

Tags: c++, binary, output, binaryfiles

the task is that I need to write a pre-initialized structure to a binary file, and then get the first three and last two elements from this file and copy them to a new file. Now I have a program that only writes my data-structure to a binary file, but I do not know how to access the first three and last two elements of a given structure, and then write them to a new binary file. Can you explain how to access the data in a binary file?

```
#include "iostream"
#include "fstream"
#include <string>
using namespace std;
struct timeOfFlight {
    int hours;
    int minutes;
};

struct flight {
    int numberOfRace;
    char type[50];
    timeOfFlight departureTime;
};

int main() {
    flight trip[] = {{105, "passanger", 1,  50},
                       {321, "cargo", 8,  8},
                       {32,  "passanger", 15, 6},
                       {215,"cargo", 20, 44},
                       {123, "passanger", 11, 14},
                       {543, "cargo", 3,  10},
                       {657, "passanger", 5,  30},
                       {126, "cargo", 7,  15},
                       {135, "passanger", 8,  40},};
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open("C:\\new.txt", ios_base::binary);
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
        fout << trip[i].numberOfRace
        << trip[i].type
        << trip[i].departureTime.hours
        << trip[i].departureTime.minutes;
        cout << "Number of race: " << trip[i].numberOfRace << " Type of plane: " << trip[i].type << " Time for flight: "
             << trip[i].departureTime.hours << " hours " << trip[i].departureTime.minutes << " minutes\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: `ofstream fin;` is confusing naming.

Comment: Search the internet for "C++ read binary file".  There are already a plethora of similar questions on the internet or StackOverflow.

Comment: Use [`fout.write`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) instead of stream operators to write data to a binary file.

Comment: it you use stream operators then it is not a binary file.

Comment: @MarekR You can still use stream operators on a binary file.  The primary difference is with a file in **binary** mode, there are no translations.  For example the newline is not translated and neither are control characters.  On some platforms, the newline `\n` is translated into `\r\n` when not in binary mode.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I'm aware. Problem is that for example `out << intValue` will not write binary representation of integer, but its text representation, so stream is not purely binary after all.

Comment: @MarekR: I've seen binary files and streams that have ASCII characters.  Are you saying that a binary file can't have ASCII characters or numbers in text format?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews no, but binary files aren't necessarily text files. If your structure has an int, you don't store "127", but instead you store raw bytes, some of which will be zero.